# Issue with operator-> overloaded in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, operator-overloading, intellisense, smart-pointers

I've implemented a small framework in C++ which I use in a course I give at college, to help students implement their homework. One of the most valuable classes of that framework, is a smart pointer class, which as you can imagine, it overloads the `->` operator.

Recently I upgraded from VS2008 to VS2010, and occasionally I get issues with the intellisense after typing the operator. Instead of showing the methods and fields available in the pointed data type, it shows the methods and fields of the smart pointer class. Note this doesn't happen all the time, but once it happens, it's a little frustrating because I end up wasting a lot of time.

Have you experienced any trouble like this? Any idea or suggestion to work around this will be very appreciated.

This may sound like a minor issue, but It invalidates the use of VS2010 in the course till I can work this out.

Thanks in advanced!

**EDIT**

I've managed to reproduce the issue in a smaller context. Suppose I have something like this:

```
template <class T>
struct ptr
{
  T* operator->(){ return 0; }
  void otherMember() {}
};

template <class T>
struct node
{
  T value;
};

template <class T>
void foo()
{
  ptr<node<int>> pi;
  ptr<node<T>> pt;
  pi->value = 10; // OK, intellisense shows 'value'
  pt-> // wrong! intellisense shows 'operator->()' and 'otherMember()', instead of 'value'
}
```

Does anyone experience the same behavior?

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure you're not using a pointer to your smart pointer?

Comment: Intellisense worked last I checked. Post some code so we can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Martin, no, I'm not defining pointers to pointers

Comment: @jalf, I'll edit my question to add some more background

Comment: just a comment, when this happens you can delete the .sdf file to rebuild the intellisense database.  you can also open a bug at http://connect.microsoft.com/ and folks will take a look at it.

Comment: @Rick, thanks for the tip, though it didn't solve the issue in this case. I'll try going for the bug report, and see how lucky I am

Comment: If you send to microsoft connect, reduce your test case (e.g., remove operator==) and add the Table<> class too.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble with the std::tr1::shared_ptr class

Comment: I've added an issue in connect.microsoft.com as it was suggested. Now we only can hope this gets heard by the adequate people before the release of SP1. The url to the issue is https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/621106/intellisense-error-in-c-type-that-overloads-operator

Comment: This looks like a bug report for a particular software version. The question was asked long ago and probably is obsolete.

Comment: @SergeyK.the bug remains unsolved. I've posted bug reports in Connect, and send frowns through VS 2012 to 2015, but the issue remains.